# Python: how to annotate operator dunder methods?

Tags: python, operator-overloading, overloading, typing

Suppose I have a class `A` with support to the `+` operation, so that instances of `A` can be added to other instances of `A`, and the result is another instance of `A`. For example:

```
class A:
    ...

    def __add__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, A):
            return NotImplemented
        else:
            return A(self._value + other._value)  # or whatever
```

How should I annotate that method? I can think of three options, none of which sounds great to me.

## Header for all three options

I'll use Python 3.11's `Self` for simplicity, but that's not important.

```
from types import NotImplementedType
from typing import Any, Self, overload
```

## Option 1

```
def __add__(self, other: Self) -> Self:
```

This feels like lying to me, since it's possible that `__add__` will return `NotImplemented`. Also (as Richard Ambler mentioned in the comments), `other` might not be an instance of `A`, and therefore shouldn't be annotated as `Self`.

## Option 2

```
def __add__(self, other: Any) -> Self | NotImplementedType:
```

Now, it looks to the type checker that the type of `A() + A()` is `A | NotImplementedType`, and then after `obj=A()+A(); f(obj);` I would get some warnings like "expected an `A` but `obj` might be `NotImplemented`".

## Option 3:

```
@overload
def __add__(self, other: A) -> Self: ...
@overload
def __add__(self, other: Any) -> Self | NotImplementedType: ...

def __add__(self, other):
   ...  # implementation
```

I can't test this yet because apparently mypy hasn't implemented `Self`, but this looks like it should work fine. However, it does feel way more verbose than I expected it to be, since this functionality is honestly quite standard boilerplate.

---

Is there a documented best practice? Be it one of the above methods, or another one I haven't thought of?

Comment: Are you sure you'd want to return a `NotImplementedType` rather than raise a `NotImplementedError`?

Comment: yes I am; that's exactly what `NotImplemented` is for: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types

Comment: [As far as I understand](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html#implementing-the-arithmetic-operations), the reason to return a `NotImplemented` would be to show that you expect the interpreter to then check whether `other` has an appropriate `__radd__` defined that handles type `A`, which might indeed be what you want. In that case, I don't think it would be appropriate to annotate `other: Self` since you are expecting it to sometimes be something else.

Comment: Yes that's a good reason to dismiss option 1